# How to create shortcut on home screen to count time

Tags: android, shortcut, homescreen

I have an application consists of a button, that starts counting time whenever the button is pressed, and finishes counting when it is pressed again, and so on.

What I want is a shortcut on home screen (if possible, a floating button; if not, just a shortcut) to do the same action as that button.

Is it possible to define actions for shortcuts? how can I achieve that? minSdkVersion = 16.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the library [link](https://github.com/andremion/CounterFab) which creates a counter floating action bar.

And [Here](https://www.journaldev.com/14673/android-floating-widget) is the tutorial to make that FAB floating like in facebook messenger app.

What it does is it display's a floating action button as the overlay view when the application is in the background.

[image]

Comment: it helped me in making floating button, and I used "widgets" to implement stopwatch.